# blink background image in css

Tags: html, css

I want to blink my bg image using css.

It should blink quickly and I have no idea how to do it.

I can only use HTML and CSS.

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image : url('bg.jpg');
  animation: blinkingBackground 2s infinite;
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
```

I have also added

```
animation: blinkingBackground 2s infinite;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Please post your css about blinkingBackground animation

Comment: Please post enough HTML along with the keyframes of blinkingBackground so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ahmad's solution is good, but it doesn't fade in smoothly. So I made a code which makes the blinking smoother.

```css
.html_bg {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/macOSBigSur.jpg);
  animation: blink 1.5s infinite;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="html_bg">
  <!--Put your content here-->
</div>
```

I made the opacity change to zero at 50% so that the opacity can change back to 1 smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```css
.html_image {
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/686/536/354.jpg?hmac=nQKjRmIoZtUkWvI-wNF8RFNW89VHuPIPT2muuPPL3QY');
  height: 200px;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="html_image">
  
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o3cgbyv/)